# Why can we use function pointers both as (*func_ptr)() and func_ptr() to invoke a function,but not so for array pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers, pointer-to-array

Suppose we have a function pointer `func_ptr` of type `void (*func_ptr)()`.Then we know that using this we can invoke the function using this pointer both as :

```
    (*func_ptr)();
    func_ptr();
```

But again, suppose we have a pointer to an integer array `int (*arr_ptr)[5]`, then why can't we refer to the array as `arr_ptr[]`, and consequently its elements as `arr_ptr[0]`,`arr_ptr[1]` etc? Why can we only use `(*arr_ptr)[0]` and `(*arr_ptr)[1]`?

Comment: It's actually even more indirect: Functions can *only* be called via function pointers. But a function expression immediately decays into a function pointer. So when you say `foo()`, you're actually saying `(&foo)()`, but that's implicit.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks Kerrec,it makes the whole thing much clearer,complements pmg's answer well if appended at the end of that.

Comment: @KerrekSB If it's no bother can you take a look at the other question of mine?It will take a few seconds  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373465/can-bit-fields-only-be-fields-of-a-structure-union-never-normal-stand-alone

Comment: you can also invoke it as `(*****func_ptr)();` :)

Comment: @newacct Jesus Christ!!Never imagined that!! Can you kindly tell me the reason why that works?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: Well, when you dereference a function pointer, you get an expression of function type (technically a "function designator"). However, when used in most contexts, such a function expression will be implicitly converted back to a function pointer that points to itself. (This is similar to how in most contexts, an expression of array type will be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.) You can repeat this "loop" as many times as you want.

Comment: @newacct I ran your code and I am amazed any number of ***** works!!Should I post it in a different question?Your answer seems too tough to grasp!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `arr_ptr[0]` is `int [5]`; the type of `(*arr_ptr)[0]` is `int`. If you wanted to, you could use `arr_ptr[0][0]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int (*arr_ptr)[5];
  int a[2][5] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};
  arr_ptr = a;
  printf("%d %d\n", (*arr_ptr)[2], arr_ptr[1][2]);
  return 0;
}
```

You can see the [code "running" at ideone](http://ideone.com/NTLpQk).

That a function pointer can be used either way is just (*nice*) sintactic sugar.

Comment: `That a function pointer can be used either way is just (nice) sintactic sugar.` ---I too had a gut feeling about that.Thanks for confirming it!!

Comment: I would appreciate if you can look into this following question of mine  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373465/can-bit-fields-only-be-fields-of-a-structure-union-never-normal-stand-alone

Answer (score 0):

As per ISO/IEC 2011 `6.3.2.1/4`

```
A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when 
it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator,65) 
or the unary & operator, **a function designator with type
‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has 
type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’ ** .
```

again `6.7.6.3 Function declarators` says it in lengths.

now what does this mean? when we call a function with its declarator it is converted to a pointer of that type, so then both need to represent the same function. i.e foo and &foo are the same. how do you check this? my dumb way of doing this is(Please dont do this)

```
int s(){return 100;}
int a = &s;
int a = s;
```

now both give the same error!

now your question
    **"we have a pointer to an integer array"** which means it is of type `int (*)[]` so when we want to access the 2nd element,for example, we need `(*ptr)[1]`.  //@1

same rule applies for function pointers, for example

```
 int (*p)(void)    //`p` pointer to function type
```

now suppose if we **could have had** array of functions(which we cannot) and we need a pointer to this type of array we need

```
--> `int ((*fp)[5])(void)`  //which is not possible but lets assumme we can,
```

then we need to access the second function, for eg, as `(*fp)[1]`. which is similar to @1.

but as standard says

function declarator is converted to pointer to a function of that type which means

if we have a function say

```
int foo()
{
    return 100;
}
```

we can call this function in the following ways

```
1) foo()
2) (&foo)()
3) (*foo)()
```

the `1)` and `2)` are same as `3)` because 1) is converted to `3)`(as in standard) and as for `2)` it is possible for a `int (*fp)(void) = &foo` is same as int `(*fp)(void) = foo;`

Comment: i have augmented the previous answer, both should help.