# Can bit-fields only be fields of a structure/union, never "normal", "stand-alone" variables?

Tags: c, variables, bit-fields

The field part of bit-fields seems to suggest that they can only be fields inside a structure or union.

Can a bit-field be a typical "stand-alone" variable, outside any aggregate data-type like union or structure as follows:

```
   int sum:6;   //Can this work as a declaration statement?
   sum=4;
```

If not, why so? If bit-fields are basically intended to use less memory, why can't we declare any variable as a bit-field if we know it won't exceed that size?

Comment: There are no "stand-lone" bitfields. It really makes no sense. You already have integral types of all conceivable sizes (e.g. `uint8_t`), and there's nothing gainable from "using fewer bits". Addressing is quite possibly *slower* when using anything that's not machine word sized anyway.

Comment: @KerrekSB LOL, I got my answer through a comment!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bit-fields are only part of structs or unions because that's what the C [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) allows. It would have been possible to decide differently. Why the committee decided to write the standard the way it is, you would have to ask them.

To find the information in the C99 standard:

From the table of contents:

6.7 Declarations

6.7.2 Type specifiers (okay, this one is a little bit obscure)

6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers.

One bit-field is the `declarator_opt : constant-expression` part of the syntax. This syntax is only allowed here, and a consequence is that one cannot declare bit-fields elsewhere.

The syntax tells you that the name of a bit-field can optionally be omitted, if you were curious for this sort of information. Clause 6.7.2.1:3 goes further and prohibits names for 0-length bit-fields.

Comment: `Why the committee decided to write the standard the way it is, you would have to ask them.` He was asking us!

Answer (score 0):

Bit fields can only be defined in structs and unions where they can be referred to individually by name.
You cannot address memory by bits, a minimum of a byte size is required (8 bits).
In order to address a variable bit by bit, you may use a mask like so:

```
int num = 9;
int fourthBit = (num >> 4) & 1;
```

A struct can have a bigger size, for example an int (of 4 bytes) and then be divided, by bits, to different pieces. Of course, the assignment will be compiled using masks.

Refer to this for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: A multiple of a byte is used even when you use bitfields in a structure.It's never like "2 bytes and 5 bits".But bit fields enable us to use 1,2,3 byte for an integer.So why can't they be used to do the same as "stand-alone" variables?

Comment: Your link is no help.Just carries the known stuff about bitfields,not the answer to my question.

Comment: My answer refers to your first question: "Can this work as a declaration statement". As for your second question - why, I think its related to the the language syntax and syntax rules. In order for you to refer to a bit in a variable, there would have been some kind of syntax to support it, something like: num$bit4 or something like that. But there is already a syntax for doing something similar, using a dot like so: num.bit4 so I guess they used this and required that referring to bits in a variable be via a struct. I will try to find a reference for this.

Comment: I never said my statement `int sum:6` expects bits!! It's obvious that I expect 1 byte as I would have had it been in a structure like `struct test{int sum:6};`.

Comment: And where in my question I said I intend to access a single individual bit?I am talking about the variable stored in the bitfield.

Comment: I dont understand your statement. Could you please rephrase the specific question?

Comment: While using bit-fields we expect the size to be rounded to the nearest byte multiple,not the multiple of the size of a datatype like `int`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I just want to be sure I understand you. What do you mean by "not the multiple of the size of a datatype like int", and why would "sum" be allocated 4 bits (and not 6, like in the example in your question)? Could you please give a proper example of what you mean so I can refer to your question properly?

Comment: “Bit fields can only be defined in structs” No, bit-fields can be defined in structs and unions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You addressed that to me or SatA?Because I have mentioned both in my question--Structures and unions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Why don't you elaborate Kerrek's answer and post it so that my question will have at least one proper answer instead of the only downvoted answer?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture because there is little to say. Bit-fields are only part of structs or unions because that's what the C standard allows. It would have been possible to decide differently. Why the committee decided to write the standard the way it is, you would have to ask them. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Comment: @PascalCuoq **Bit-fields are only part of structs or unions ** that's what I wanted to hear.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You linked me the whole standard!!In which part it's mentioned that bitfields are only part of structs or unions?What keyword to search to get there?

Comment: @PascalCuoq thanks for your remark. I edited the answer. Didn't feel like there was a need to point that out regarding the original question. Though its always good to be 100% correct for others who see this question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> If not, why so? If bit-fields are basically intended to use less memory, why can't we >declare any variable as a bit-field if we know it won't exceed that size?

Because the memory is fixed at 16 or 32 bits wide.  It would be too slow to pack a users 14 bit ints into 16 bits and use the other 2 bits . Its better to waste the 2 bits and don't let you define in efficient storage. Thats why if you really want to you can use a union.
You wouldn't be gaining anything by making the compiler work harder for nothing.